# Set prototype cell height tableviewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm working with tableView controller and I set an height of 200px to my prototype cell, but when I build and run the cell doesn't have an height of 200px.
How can I solve it?

This is my UITableViewController class:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
   }
}
```

Comment: do you add the height using story board?

Comment: yes I do this --

Comment: Is the delegate method even called? Are you using Static cells? You say that your cell doesn't have the correct height, but is it visible at all? I mean, you don't assure that you did the other filling methods (cellForRow, numberOfRows, etc.à

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
```

Comment: No, I add the override function into tableViewController class but it doesn't work. Thank you anyway.